# Cannot upload .CSV via form on Mac computer

Tags: php, macos, csv, upload, form-submit

I have a script that takes a .CSV and uploads it and processes it via PHP. It works fine on all browsers via Windows. On the otherhand, OSX, it fails to uploads. It instantly posts the form without loading the data. I've tried making sure that the .csv file has the extension on OSX. Thank you in advanced if you can help.

```
<form name="batchUpload" id="batchUpload" class="navbar-form pull-left" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="uploadCSV" id="uploadCSV" type="file" class="button" accept=".csv"> 
    <input name="companyID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['companyID'])?>">
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="batchUpload"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-medium btn-info" id="submit-upload" style="margin:5px 0 0 20px;">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you generally DON'T put in a `.` on the accept attribute. e.g. `accept="csv"`. Putting in the `.` implies you want to allow `somefile..csv`.

Comment: Well that solved my problem. I don't know why I didn't see that. Thanks!